# How to protect files created by FileConnection from being manually deleted and modified?

Tags: security, mobile, java-me, midp, jsr75

Suppose there is a `file` created in the filesystem of a mobile device by using `FileConnection` ( J2ME ). How to make programmatically this file undeletable and unupdatable `manually` ?

Comment: Was this file created on a public folder? For example, inside an SD Card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tyr to hidden the files programatically and remember the names.